# Why is that (all) database authentication is still done with usernames and passwords?

Tags: database

This is something I have been thinking about a lot recently - why do we still authenticate / connect to databases with usernames and passwords?

Hear me out.

Lets talk about production databases. I think it is a safe assumption to make, that when it comes to production databases, there should never be a situation where a human needs to directly connect to a production database and make changes. Anything even remotely close to this would be done through some kind of administrative CRUD-interface / program.

On the other hand, wouldn't we also agree that the reason why username and password based authentication exists is that it is specifically intuitive for humans to use?

These two "facts" together make a very little sense to me. We have a production database that should not be touched by humans, yet the only way to authenticate / connect to it is via username+password method made specifically for humans.

This begs the question of what is going on with database authentication? Lets put the aforementioned this way: When we have a production database, since **no humans should access it**, it follows that **only programs** do and should **access it**.

Well since it is only accessed by different programs, why aren't we e.g. digitally signing our programs against the database and derive the database access from there? If someone makes unapproved changes to our database accessing program or tries to use a unsigned program to access the database, it simply would not work.

Now the only thing we have to worry about is the signing key and development database credentials.  This signing key has no reason to get even near a repository or any such place where it could possibly leak somewhere, whereas developers mistakenly push their database credentials into version control and / or keep copies of the credentials god knows where... daily. There is nothing to steal, nothing default, nothing to void and nothing to brute-force either.

**So am I missing something or why do we still authenticate and connect to our databases with usernames and passwords?**

Comment: see [On discussions and why they don't make good questions](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6742/31260)

Comment: "there should never be a situation where a human needs to directly connect to a production database and make changes" In a production incident when everything is on fire, sometimes I really, really need that "break glass" root access to my database.

Comment: As @philipp-kendall points out, your initial assumption is wrong (not the part that normally humans should not touch it, but the "never" part). There are situations when humans need to access the database to fix things. Waiting for development/testing/sign-off/release cycles for a tool that can fix the database which may take days isn't always the best thing to do.

Comment: An additional aspect is that most database systems are OLD. Username/password schemes were there for a long time, legacy applications depend on it, etc. Adding additional authentication schemes might make sense for new applications but won't make the old ones go away. And your scheme of digitally signing the program would not work, as the database has no way of ensuring that it isn't being contacted by an unsigned or tampered programs. Signing programs only works in the context of an operating system which may refuse to execute unsigned software.

Comment: `This signing key has no reason to get even near a repository or any such place where it could possibly leak somewhere.` Neither the credentials user/pass. I'm actually working on a project which has no credentials whatsoever and it's integrated with 1 DB (per env) and 9 remote services (per env). Security is far more than hiding information. You can define a whole administrative and technical protocol around that.

Comment: Password auth makes secret manageemnt pretty convenient, and is not that terribly problematic. Greatest issue would be the lack of server authentication, making basic password auth phishable and unsuitable for zero-trust systems. But that's not a problem when using TLS connections where the server presents a cert. Also, mainstream databases like [Postgres offer a lot of different auth options](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/15/client-authentication.html), including Kerberos and TLS client certificates.

Answer (score 3):

> digitally signing our programs against the database and derive the database access from there

This doesn't actually work. Or rather, technologies exist to try to lock access to specific programs in a way that is difficult for a human without the required keys to change, but they are extremely inflexible and difficult to use.

Comment: plus it assumes that there are language and environment agnostic systems in place to allow software to communicate its signature securely to the database server, but none that would allow username/password to be securely communicated. Which tbh makes no sense whatsoever.